# Android App is running on some devices but doesn't on another devices...How to solve that?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, crash

My app is perfectly running on Huawei Y9 prime which has android 10 and it crashes on Redmi Note 4 which has android 6. I made the project with Android 5...While I am installing the app on Redmi note 4 it isn't starting...A white screen comes for a very short time and the floats down...No error is shown in logcat, but this is shown in "Run" and that too when I click the app icon 3-4 times -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.js11.a8minutesworkout, PID: 29896
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.js11.a8minutesworkout/com.js11.a8minutesworkout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    at com.js11.a8minutesworkout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
    at com.js11.a8minutesworkout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
    at com.js11.a8minutesworkout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.js11.a8minutesworkout:drawable/item_color_accent_border_ripple_background" (7f07008c) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07008c a=-1 r=0x7f07008c}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2646)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3955)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
    at com.js11.a8minutesworkout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

MainActivity code -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

    window.navigationBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundColor)

    llStart.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, ExerciseActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    llBMI.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, BMIActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    llHistory.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, HistoryActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}

drawable/item_color_accent_border_ripple_background -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#000000" /><!--ye color jahe jo bhi rkho isse frk nh pdne wala-->
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_circular_color_accent_border" />
```

I am new to android developing and I am very frustrated with this problem..

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: dont use this in any click listener instead user MainActivity.this

Comment: Check "com.js11.a8minutesworkout:drawable/item_color_accent_border_ripple_background". Android is not able to find this resource.

Are you adding this in any specific values directory?

Comment: AnujMathur_07, if android wasn't able to find this resource then the app wouldn't run on Huawei Y9 Prime also, but it's running on that...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change android sdk version.
in androidmanifest.xml file.
targetsdkversion and minsdkversion first check.

Answer (score -1):

```
llStart.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, ExerciseActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

llBMI.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, BMIActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

llHistory.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

only `this` will point to the parent function that is onclicklistener, so you want to use activity's context then you should use `className.this`

Comment: why would intent even compile if you were passing in the wrong type of variable ?

Comment: in which line r u getting error ?? and it was the error ??

Comment: you have to read the actual question OP has given, they are getting a stack trace. that means the app is running. it won't run if you pass through the wrong values to parameters

Comment: a_local_nobody, Yes you are right...if It was wrong than the app wouldn't run on Huawei Y9 prime, but it's running on that....